# AppArmor - failed to start

Tags: apparmor

On my Ubuntu server 18.04 I have next error:

```
sudo service apparmor status
● apparmor.service - AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-06-10 07:37:20 CEST; 11s ago
     Docs: man:apparmor(7)
           http://wiki.apparmor.net/
  Process: 22057 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apparmor start (code=exited, status=123)
 Main PID: 22057 (code=exited, status=123)

Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn systemd[1]: Starting AppArmor initialization...
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn apparmor[22057]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn apparmor[22057]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn apparmor[22057]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn apparmor[22057]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn apparmor[22057]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn apparmor[22057]:    ...fail!
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=123/n/a
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 10 07:37:20 kacn systemd[1]: Failed to start AppArmor initialization.
```

After reading (some old stuff), it should be a bug, but it is strange, that it isn't solved yet?
I have tried with: `sudo apt install apparmor.easyprof` but it doesn't help.